# Change redirect login page apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

There is someway to change the redirect for some specifically page 
instead to go right to the Home page?
I tried to create a branch, but this isn't working, sometime i cold do punting the branch on processing, but if i do, he ignore my login schema.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are saying. Also, there seem to be some typos ("punting"? "cold"?) so I'll guess: when you create a branch, make sure that you place it to the right position (order, sequence).

If Apex has already created a branch whose sequence is 10 and which takes action on page submit (and redirects to, for example, page 8), and then you create your own branch (sequence 20) which also fires on page submit but goes to page 22, then  the one with lower sequence will take precedence.

I wouldn't know what you mean by "ignoring your login schema". What is it?

**[EDIT]**

Aha; I think I understand now what you meant - after logging in, you want to redirect to some other page, different from the default one.

If that's so, then

- click "Edit application properties" button (upper right hand corner of the App. Builder, when you're in that application).
- click "User interface" tab
- click "Edit" icon (a pencil) at the beginning of the "Desktop" user interface
- modify "Home URL" value. For example, if it was `f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.` (go to page 1), set it to `f?p=&APP_ID.:4:&SESSION.` (go to page 4)

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: My keyboard isn't work very well, sorry for the Typos.

Comment: My problems is, when you do the logon on the page 101 on apex, it automatic redirect for the home page

i would change that, and automatic redirect from the login page to My own page

Comment: OK; you can edit your own message (question) and fix those typos, if you think that they'll make us understand you better.

Comment: @Amorim, I have edited my answer; please, have a look.